# open last modified file in the directory using vi

Tags: bash, vi, tcsh

I want a quick way to open the last modified file in the directory, perhaps in a form of alias.

Currently, I do ls -ltr. Then copy-and-paste the filename

Assume that I am using tcsh

Comment: Why the Bash tag if you're using tcsh?

Comment: I think that's find here; the answer works in bash as well.

Answer (score 21):

```
vi `ls -tr | tail -1`
```

Comment: May want to add --groups-directories-first to the ls, that way files are always at the end.

Comment: i saved file using :x firstVimFile.txt using Vim for Windows and it quit dont know where file got saved and how to open it back..:/

Answer (score 2):

Creating an alias for the mentioned answer will avoid typing the command every time.

Add below entry in `.tcshrc` file and reload.

```
alias v='vi `ls -tr | tail -1`'
```

To avoid going to log folder and executing the command, create below alias and reload.

```
alias -- -='cd -'
alias v='cd /path/to/log/folder; vi `ls -tr | tail -1` ; -'
```