# global alias for last file in current directory

Tags: shell, command-line, alias, zsh

I often want to perform a function on the most recent file in the current directory. Essentially I want a more general version of a method to [open last modified file in the directory using vi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066636/open-last-modified-file-in-the-directory-using-vi).

I am able to write a global alias in zsh that does part of what I need:

```
alias -g lafi='`ls -rt|tail -n 1`'
```

Now I can execute something like

```
cat lafi
```

and I will see the content of the most recent file in the current dir. Or I can issue `echo lafi` to figure out what the last file was (or I could even say `ls -rt|tail -n 1`).

Is there a way to modify the alias definition such that it outputs the last file (to STDERR?) and then hands it on like `lafi` above for further consumption in the commandline?. So for the above `cat lafi` I would hope for this output.

```
last file: <name of last-file>
<content of last-file>
```

I suspect this involves `tee` but my shell kung fu doesn't cover this in sufficient detail.

Comment: `zsh` allows the more efficient command `print *(.Om[-1])` to replace the pipeline. This is also safer, as it avoids parsing the output of `ls` which fails for file names containing newlines.

Comment: Could you work this into an answer and then I can accept it?

Comment: Just consider it an optimization to Glenn's answer: `alias -g lafi='$(print *(.om[1]) | tee ...)'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps

```
alias -g lafi='`ls -rt | tail -n 1 | tee >({ printf "last file: "; cat; } >&2)`'
```

I think zsh has process substitutions like that.

Comment: One issue with this is that something like `echo lafi 2>/dev/null` will *not* suppress the "last file" comment, since the `tee` command is inheriting its standard error from the shell; the local redirection does not apply. Just something to be aware of depending on the use case.